# What is the best way to model a one-to-many relationship that also has a "selected" object in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

In our app, a user can be a member of many organizations. While viewing the site, they are generally viewing it through one of those organizations. This is the selected organization.

Is the following model the best way to model that? Is there a way to model it so you don't have to have the `selectedBy` and `selectedById` on the `Membership` and just have the `selectedMembershipId` on the `User` with a foreign key to the `Membership`?

```
model User {
  id                 Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  memberships        Membership[] @relation("Memberships")
  selectedMembership Membership?  @relation("Selection")
}
model Membership {
  id           Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  user         User         @relation("Memberships", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId       Int
  selectedBy   User?        @relation("Selection", fields: [selectedById], references: [id])
  selectedById Int?          @unique
  organization Organization @relation(fields: [orgId], references: [id])
  orgId        Int
  role         MemberRole

  @@unique([userId, orgId])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do *precisely* what you're hoping to. The syntax for relations in prisma calls for having a relation field (To the best of my understanding, that's what you would prefer not to have in your schema).

Since it's a one-to-one relation, if you prefer, you could do it the other way around, and have a `selectedMembershipId` foreign key on the `User` side and only have the `selectedBy` relation field on the `Membership` side like this:

```
model User {
  id                 Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  memberships        Membership[] @relation("Memberships")
  selectedMembership Membership?  @relation("Selection", fields: [selectedMembershipId], references: [id])
  selectedMembershipId       Int?         @unique

}

model Membership {
  id         Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  user       User  @relation("Memberships", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     Int
  selectedBy User? @relation("Selection")
  ...
}
```

However, this is really a matter of preference regarding which side to keep the foreign key. In my opinion, the way you're handling your schema is the most reasonable way to model the relationship in Prisma.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. I posted a follow up question that was closed when it was part of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891527/better-way-to-perform-this-relation-transaction-in-prisma

Comment: Provided a response, hope it helps :D. Btw, we have a very active [slack](https://slack.prisma.io/) which you could check out, if you have more questions or just want to learn more about Prisma.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Do you prefer asking on slack, on here or on github?

Comment: We try to stay on top of questions on all three, so whatever is most convenient for you :D.