# Better way to perform this Relation "transaction" in Prisma

Tags: prisma

I posted a question yesterday that has the relevant prisma schema which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885191/what-is-the-best-way-to-model-a-one-to-many-relationship-that-also-has-a-select).

As a follow up question, when a member creates a new `Organization`, I'd like for it to become their selected `Membership`. The only way I've found to do this is to deselect their current `Memebership` (set it to `null`), do the `create`, then restore the relationship if that `create` didn't work. I have to use `updateMany` for that initial operation in case there is no `selectedMembership`. Is that right?

```
//Deselect the currently selected Org
const updatedMembership = await prisma.membership.updateMany({
    where: {
        selectedById: user.id
    },
    data: {
        selectedById: null
    }
});
if (updatedMembership) {
    //Select the new one.
    const result = await prisma.organization.create({
        data: {
            name: body.name,
            members: {
                create: [{
                    role: MemberRole.OWNER,
                    userId: user.id,
                    selectedById: user.id
                }]
            }
        },
    });
    if (result) {
        res.status(200)
            .json(result);
    } else {
        //Restore the previously selected one if the create failed
        if(user.selectedMembership) {
            await prisma.membership.update({
                where: {
                    id: user.selectedMembership?.id
                },
                data: {
                    selectedById: user.id
                }
            });
        }
        res.status(500).end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`connect` API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-an-existing-record) to do all of this in a single query. Just make sure that the `user.id` is valid.

Here's a much cleaner version of the create and update query logic in your question:

```js
const result = await prisma.organization.create({
        data: {
            name: body.name,
            members: { 
                create: {  
                    role: MemberRole.OWNER,
                    user: {
                        connect: {
                            id: user.id,  // making the user a member of the organization
                        },
                    },
                    selectedBy: {
                        connect: {
                            id: user.id,  // selecting the newly created membership as the user's default organization
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

This will handle all cases, regardless of whether the `user` with `id = user.id` currently:

- Is a member of other organization(s) and has another membership as their default
- Is a member of other organization(s) but has no default membership
- Is not a member of any organization and has no default membership

Comment: Thanks Tasin. This worked great. I'm not sure how I missed the connect syntax while looking over the doc/googling. I'm going to read through it all more carefully.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!